# How can I fix the `TryRefreshAsync not found` error?

Tags: c#, azure, configuration, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-3.1

As part of a migration of my project from the .NET Core to .NET 6 I upgraded the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration` from the `4.5.0` to the `6.0.0`.

After that with any of my request I am getting the following error:

> Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.IConfigurationRefresher.TryRefreshAsync()'.

I searched for the `TryRefreshAsync` across my whole solution and I am not using this method anywhere explicitly.

Also, I checked the documentation over [here](https://github.com/Azure/AppConfiguration/blob/main/releaseNotes/MicrosoftExtensionsConfigurationAzureAppConfiguration.md) and it states that the method should be present in the `6.0.0`.

Could someone help me to understand what am I missing here, please?

**UPDATE**

I was able to pinpoint who is trying to call the method. In my case it is the:

> at Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration.AspNetCore.AzureAppConfigurationRefreshMiddleware.d__5.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the `Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration`. Updating it from the `4.5.0` to the `6.0.0` fixed the issue.